# Need to get the value from HIDDEN type html in Selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to get a value of the element which TYPE of the element is HIDDEN. THe value is showing in html element but not able to get the value coz TYPE is hidden. Someone please help me in this.

```
<input type="HIDDEN" label_value="Sub Reference" title="Sub Reference"      id="ACC_NO" dbt="BK_ACC" dbc="SUBREFNO" name="SUBREFNO" dtype="VARCHAR2" size="" required="" aria-required="false" class="hidden" value="9875365">
```

Above is my html element. I used getAttribute("value") not able to take the value of the element.Please help

Comment: If you are trying to accomplish a user scenario, how would the user get the value? There's likely something they have to click, etc. to get that element to become visible. Use Selenium to do whatever is needed to make the element visible and then you can get the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JavascriptExecuter` in selenium to make hidden element visible and then get the value of `<input>` tag

Use below Code :

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("ACC_NO"));

js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('type', '')",element);

System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("ACC_NO")).getAttribute("value"));
```

Comment: glade to hear :). Happy coding